# Finding closest parent for two nodes

Tags: binary-tree

what is the best way to find closest parents for two given nodes on the tree?
So if I have:

```
                1
              /   \ 
             2     3
            / \   / \
           4  5  6   7
```

closest parent for 5 and 6 would be one.
Thanks

Comment: What is the input you have and the tree representation used? For example are you given the root, each node has pointers to children and you know the two node values to look for? Are you given instead the nodes and each node has a pointer to the parent? Is may be a pointer-less complete binary tree and you are give the two node indexes?

Comment: I've tried: as long as our parent are different we are are parents and do the check again.

Comment: Closest parent for both will be on same level. So, I'd first determine how far from root is each node, then on the node thats farther away, I'd climb back up to same depth as other node, then climb by on node on both until you get to same node...

Comment: A questino asked about 20 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172252/lowest-common-ancestor-of-any-rooted-tree. It links to even older solution...

Comment: Apparently some class just got some homework to do. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is called Lowest Common Ancestor(LCA) problem. (Google it)

One query can be answered by simply climbing up along their `parent` links until they meet:

The first step is to let the lower node climb until they are in the same `height`.

The second step is to let them climb simultaneously until they meet at the same node.

Then that node is the LCA of these two node.

If you need to process multiple queries, you need to use more advanced algorithm. The most time-efficient algorithm use **O(n)** time to preprocess, and **O(1)** time for each query, where **n** is the total nodes in the tree.